# How to use several databases in Asp.net core project

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework

I have a project using Asp.net core 2.1, I'm using identity stuff, now we need to add another section, let's say another sub project related to the main project, but the users table should be different as we need additional info from the user not needed in the main project also the login is not the same.

How I can handle this? add new project under the work space? add new database?

Comment: It seems you need to have two different web application projects. Sharing some common assemblies for business logic (if needed), having different membership/authentication and authorization system.

Answer (score 1):

**You can add many database as you wish, just you have to define multiple DbContext and there Connection Strings in your project.**

Add many DbContext in Startup.cs class as below :

```
services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options => options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));

services.AddDbContext<UserApplicationDbContext>(options => options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("IdentityDataConnection")));

services.AddDbContext<WebSiteDBContext>(options => options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("WebSiteConnection")));
```

and there different database Connection Strings in appsettings.json file as below :

```
"ConnectionStrings": {
"DefaultConnection": "Data Source=.;Initial Catalog=Default1;Integrated Security=True" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient;",

"IdentityDataConnection": "Data Source=.;Initial Catalog=Default2;Integrated Security=True" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient;",

"WebSiteConnection": "Data Source=.;Initial Catalog=Default3;Integrated Security=True" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient;"
```

Answer (score 0):

You could look into creating a new Area. They let you split up your application into different sections.